# How to make a ball bounce off a paddle at a certain angle depending on where it hit the paddle?

Tags: c++, math, sfml, angle, pong

So I have two separate detections for collision for both the player paddle and the enemy paddle and in the player paddle I have commented out what seems to be the math calculation needed to bounce a ball based on where it hit. The code that isn't commented simply bounces the ball around the screen as you would expect when you reverse the velocity (it's velocity is a float value) on each bounce. So for starters, is the commented out formula actually the correct formula, and if so does it need to be applied to both xSpeed and ySpeed when it collides with a paddle?

When I saw this formula it took BallAngle or PaddleAngle as an argument (I can't remember to be honest). Now if this IS the correct formula, how do I even get that angle in the first place? I'm just using integer's in there (for testing) because I don't know how to get the angle.

```
if (ball.getPosition().x < (player.getPosition().x) //PLAYER COLLISION DETECTION
&& (ball.getPosition().y + (ball.getRadius() * 2)) >= player.getPosition().y
&& ball.getPosition().y <= (player.getPosition().y + player.getSize().y))
{
    xSpeed = -xSpeed;
    //xSpeed = xSpeed*cos(91);
    //ySpeed = ySpeed*sin(90);
    ball.move(xSpeed, ySpeed);              
}

if (ball.getPosition().x > enemy.getPosition().x - 30 //ENEMY COLLISION DETECTION
&& (ball.getPosition().y + (ball.getRadius() * 2)) >= enemy.getPosition().y
&& ball.getPosition().y <= (enemy.getPosition().y + enemy.getSize().y))
{
    xSpeed = -xSpeed;
    ball.move(xSpeed, ySpeed);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect this code to do? What it actually does? Show soecific examples of its input and output.

Comment: The code as it is now just reverses the velocity so when the ball hits a paddle it bounces off at a 90 degree angle. Obviously that 90 degree angle should be based on where the ball hits the paddle (the further away from the middle, the larger the angle.

Comment: Why would the angle depend on where it hits the paddle? Is the paddle meant to be curved?

Comment: That's the way Pong has always worked. The paddles are simply rectangles. If a ball hits a paddle directly in the middle, it will bounce off horizontally. If it hits very close to the middle, but not exactly, it will bounce slightly off from horizontal, at a small angle. The angle increases the further away from the middle on both sides.

Comment: This explains the approach you wish to use I think. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/how-do-you-calculate-where-a-ball-should-go-when-it-bounces-off-the-bar

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the link. But do you happen to know what intersectY is in that link? I mean, if you were to apply a variable called intersectY to my code, what exactly does it store? All I can figure out is that it has something to do with the Y position of either the ball of paddle, because I can't really follow his actual explanation. If I can figure that out then I can easily apply the formula to my code and it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`cos(91)` is just under -1, presumably it is meant to reverse the X direction and slow it down due to the impact. `sin(90)` is almost one so again is presumably meant to slow it down a bit.

Of course these functions are actually quite expensive to calculate so you may as well just hard code the values.

```
const float xBounce = -0.99436746092
const float yBounce = 0.8939966636  
...
xSpeed *= xBounce;
ySpeed *= yBounce;
ball.move(xSpeed, ySpeed);
```

Comment: Those constant values are only there because 1. I was testing different values to see how it affects the angle. 2. Because I don't know how what kind of angle variable needs to act as the argument for cin() and cos(). So basically I can't put any constant value in there, otherwise it will just bounce off at a certain angle no matter where the ball hits the paddle. Asumming the formula I have commented out in the code is correct, then they should look like this, but the "angle" is what I don't understand how to calculate.  xSpeed = xSpeed*cos(Angle);
ySpeed = ySpeed*sin(Angle);